# Generate date series by month between two dates and avrage by month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, date-range, generate-series

I want to create a row for every month between two dates, the first day of every month should be the day of the start date or the first day of every month, and the last date should be the last day of every month or the end date, with average (if date start = 15, then the average should be 15/30) for my table.

input :

```
product_id | date_start | date_end
1          | 16-01-2020 | 15-03-2020
2          | 07-01-2020 | 22-04-2020
```

The result should be :

```
product_id | date_start | date_end    | average
1          | 16-01-2020 | 31-01-2020  | 0.5
1          | 01-02-2020 | 29-02-2020  | 1
1          | 01-03-2020 | 15-03-2020  | 0.5
2          | 07-01-2020 | 31-01-2020  | 0.76  -- (30-07)/30
2          | 01-02-2020 | 29-02-2020  | 1
2          | 01-03-2020 | 31-03-2020  | 1
2          | 01-04-2020 | 22-04-2020  | 0.76
```

I tried using generate series and date trunc and union

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' ):: DATE AS date_start , 
(date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '2 MONTH - 1 day' ):: DATE AS date_end

FROM generate_series( DATE '2020-01-15', DATE '2020-05-21', interval '1 MONTH' ) AS dt
union select '2020-01-15' as date_start, 
(date_trunc('month', '2020-01-15'::date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day' ):: DATE AS date_end

union select (date_trunc('month', '2020-05-21'::date) ):: DATE AS date_start ,
'2020-05-21' AS date_end
order by date_start
```

To adding average I calculate the difference between two dates

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' ):: DATE AS date_start , 
(date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '2 MONTH - 1 day' ):: DATE AS date_end,
((date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '2 MONTH - 1 day' ) - (date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' ):: DATE )
FROM generate_series( DATE '2020-01-15', DATE '2020-05-21', interval '1 MONTH' ) AS dt
```

with this it seemed like I was hit a wall.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to use `generate_series`, what (undesired) result you achieved with that, and elaborate where exactly you are stuck on?

Comment: What does "average for my table" mean exactly, how should it be computed? Do you just consider every month to be 30 days long?

Comment: @Bergi I tried use average series from date_start to date_end union two others line the first and the last, the first date_start to end of date using date_trunc + interval, for the average I calculate the difference between two date devide on 30

Comment: @Bergi I didnt check My script because the output was wrong, and I couldn't retreive the last line from my desire output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives approximately the same result as you desired, only averages deviates. I believe this stems from an inconsistency in the your calculations where the dates are inclusive in some and excludes either start or end date in others, I was inclusive in all. The other area of difference being I used the actual number of days in the month for denominator calculating it instead of 30. This is necessary for Feb to ever have average 1, otherwise max would be 0.97, and full months having 31 days would average 1.03.

```
with product_dates(product_id, date_start, date_end) as  
     ( values (1,'2020-01-16'::date,'2020-03-15'::date)
            , (2,'2020-01-07'::date,'2020-04-22'::date)
     ) 
select product_id, start_date, end_date, round((end_date-start_date+1 ) * 1.0 / (eom-som+1),2) average   
 from (select product_id
            , greatest(date_start,dt::date) start_date 
            , least(date_end,  (dt+interval '1 month' -interval '1 day')::date) end_date
            , dt::date som
            , (dt+interval '1 month' -interval '1 day')::date eom     
       from product_dates 
       cross join generate_series(date_trunc('month', date_start)
                                 ,date_trunc('month', date_end) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day' 
                                 ,interval '1 month'
                                 ) gs(dt)
      ) s1;
```

The heart is the generate_series working directly with dates, notice the date manipulation to ensure I had first day and last day of month. Then in the outer portion of the quest I selected those dates or the parameter date or the generated one (greatest and least functions),